# Android App Dropbox API On authentication, always returns IllegalStateException

Tags: android, dropbox-api

Trying to integrate dropbox into my app. I have followed all the rules as I see them, incluiding the crazy story of adding 'db-' to my app key.

I obtained app key and secret key from the dropbox app store.
The app key is installed properly in the Manifest and both keys in the dbx call:

```
mDbxAcctMgr = DbxAccountManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext(), 
    valid_app_key, valid_app_secret);
```

Strangely, the error message is: (note the 'db-db-')

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: URI scheme in your app's manifest is
>   not set up correctly. You should have a
>   com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity with the scheme:
>   db-db-es3ir5vajvxdcj5

When I remove the 'db-' portion from the APP KEY the the exception gives:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: URI scheme in your app's manifest is
>   not set up correctly. You should have a
>   com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity with the scheme:
>   db-es3ir5vajvxdcj5.

The latter makes sense.

I've tried umpteen key pairs for various name from the app store, hard-coded the strings etc

For the record, here's the section from the manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask" >
    <intent-filter>
        <data android:scheme="db-es3ir5vajvxdcj5" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<service
   android:name="com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxSyncService"
   android:enabled="true"
   android:exported="false"
   android:label="Dropbox Sync" />
```

Any ideas? Been a long day.

Richie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your manifest, you should have "db-". In other words, if your app key is "abc123", you should use "db-abc123".

In your *code* (i.e. when you're constructing the client object), you should use exactly your app key. In other words, "abc123".

Comment: Thanks smarx, I cant believe it was THAT simple. Whay a strange story, I put the app keys in resources and accessed the same key wherever! This is not a sensible key-business to me, but I was already bald to start with.